# Is there a way to retrieve any user's PhotoUrl using only their Uid?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an app that has many chat rooms, each displaying the profile images of the member users.
For quick loading, I store these URLs under each room in the real-time database.
However, if any user updates their profile picture, the stored URL will obviously be useless.
However, if I could get the current image URL for any user, using only their UID, this would no longer be an issue.

If this is not possible, are there any other common practices that would allow for the images of the users to remain current, without having to update every record across all instances of rooms containing them as members, each time they change their profile picture?

Comment: this is valid for google sign in as Tristan says, and its a good example on how to get the current user photo without saving anything to the database

Comment: I deleted my previous comment. In this situation where you are trying to get the photo for other users, you will need to save it in the DB and update it when a user changes their profile picture. There is no way to get information for other users using Auth.

Comment: yes you can, with google sign in you can get the user photo without saving nothing into firebase, since it will pull the profile photo from google servers and not from firebase

Comment: check this https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people

Comment: since you can get the photoURL you can then paste it into Glide and show user picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option will be to store the imageURL into your user id

To do this just change the reference where you are storing the photo

For example, getting the user ID

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

And then in your reference for example

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(uid).child("user_photo").setValue(your_download_url);
```

Remember that the download URL of the photo is obtained from your storage ref task.

So when you need to retrieve each users photo, just access to their reference and add a value event listener to get the data with a dataSnapshot and use Glide to show the image

**Edit**

This can work if you are doing google sign in Login in your app, you can get the user profile photo without saving anything to the database

You can get sign in information without saving it to firebase  ( just with google sign in )
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people

so you can get profile photo URL and then use Glide to show it up

Comment: How strictly does the file type have to be handled? I see that there are two points at which file type is set, in the docs: at the end of the reference and in the meta-data. In the docs they use jpg as an example. Does the ref have to end in a .[ext]? If so, do separate storage refs have to be create for each file type (.png, etc)?

Comment: To answer my own comment for anyone wondering the same thing, the 'setContentType' method for StorageMetadata, submitted as part of UploadTask, takes any String and does not have to strictly conform to the file type of what you are actually uploading.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) to lookup users by `uid`:

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    console.log(userRecord.photoURL):
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Error occurred.
  });
```